# Why are Arrow Functions in ReactJS considered as property?

Tags: reactjs, function, methods, visual-studio-code, arrow-functions

So, I've tried two different approaches as per need, i.e with Arrow Functions and Non-Arrow Functions, and while writing the code I noticed something odd about both of these, the non-arrow function i.e.

```
  close() {
    this.setState({
      show: false
    });
  }
```

are considered as method(s) which is true as they are functions,
[image: nonArrow]

But when I write an Arrow function such as:

```
  goToNextPage = () => {
    this.setState(({ page }) => ({ page: page + 1 }));
  };
```

[image: property]

It is considered a property, I quite do not understand this behavior. Is this something wrong with VSCode or it is an entirely different thing?

Comment: `aClassProperty = () => { ... }` means that you are creating a new class property for every new instance of the class, and the property is an arrow function, so it's correct. `aMethod()` is shared between every instance of the class, but in React you generally create a new function in the constructor by binding it to `this` anyway, so the end result is the same.

Comment: @Tholle Okay understood, but can you use an arrow function as `props` then?

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand what you mean. If you can do `<MyComponent aProp={this.aClassProperty} />`? Sure.

Comment: @Tholle yes that's exactly what I mean, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`class MyClass { aClassProperty = <whatever_value>; }` means that you are creating a new [class property for every new instance of the class](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-proposal-class-properties). The property can be any value you like, but in this case the property is an arrow function, so it's correct.

`aMethod()` is shared between every instance of the class, but in React you generally create a new function in the constructor by binding it to `this` anyway, so the end result is the same.

Comment: Can you expand on why React treats arrow functions as property?

Comment: @YashKaranke It's not React specific, it's how the [JavaScript proposal is laid out](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields). It doesn't matter if you write `= 2`, `= "2"`, `= function() { ... }` or even `= () => { ... }`. They're all seen as class properties.